Cisco inter-vlan routing with several routers
I am trying to enable inter-vlan routing, but something is certainly not working.
Each of the computers is assigned to corresponding vlans, every switch-to-switch and switch-to-router link is configured as trunk with vlans 10, 20 and 30 allowed. The switches have their corresponding vlans and vlan ip assigned (S1 - vlan 10, S2 - vlan 20, S3 - vlan 30). Each router has a configured subinterface assigned to the appropriate vlans. Computers can ping their gateways (subinterface IP address), but nothing else.
I need to configure static routing, but i'm not quite sure what my next hop address should be, and if i'm missing something else in the configuration.

R1 config:
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0

R2 config:
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0

R3 config:
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.3
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0

S1 config:
no spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.168.10.100 255.255.255.0

S2 config:
no spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan20
 ip address 192.168.20.100 255.255.255.0

S3 confing:
no spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan30
 ip address 192.168.30.100 255.255.255.0

S4 config (the one connected to the computers):
no spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
 switchport mode trunk


Routers route between networks - for that, they need to be attached to at least two subnets. A router with a single IP interface is useless.
Just configure all subinterfaces on R1. R2 and R3 are not required unless there are more networks behind them.
